# Can I use cheats or save files on consoles?

Tags: ps4, xbox-one

I have never had a game console before. I am really bad at gaming and generally complete PC games using cheats etc. Will I be able to do so in PS4 or X1? Do I have some way to finish the game if I am stuck at some level, say by using save files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consoles are locked platforms, "cheats" generally can't be used unless provided by the developers in the form of "cheat codes". I believe save files are locked to account on both PS4 and Xbox One.
If you want to "cheat & hack" PC is the right platform for doing so, giving far more control than consoles.